# Testing Environment

Tags: virtualization, testing

I would like to set up a 'testing environment' so that I can run applications and procedures without risking the integrity of the main installation. Is this possible? I am using Ubuntu 16.

Comment: Yes its possible a virtual machine would be great.I use this all the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its possible using a virtual machine.

Open terminal ( <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> )

Enter following commands:

```
$ sudo apt-get install virtualbox -y
$ virtualbox
```

Setting up a new virtual machine is fairly easy - just click `New` and go through the steps.  Its Fairly straight-forward so I'm not going to tell you how to do that.

Once you've made the new machine, click on `Settings`, then `Storage` (left sidebar).  You should see a CD icon with the text `Empty` - Click on that.  Under `Attributes`, click on the CD icon.  If you have an ISO file for Ubuntu, click `Choose a virtual CD/DVD disk file...`, or if you have an installation disk, click on `Host Drive`, and put the disk into the disk drive.  Click `OK`, then select your machine and click `Start`.  Go through the installation for Ubuntu, and after you reboot, go back into the same part of the settings and click on `Remove disk from virtual drive`.  Click on `Start` again, and you'll boot into a fresh installation of Ubuntu, running inside of, yet completely separate from your actual system (hence the term 'Virtual Machine').